# How to add a very long number with one comma in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some coordinate numbers (example `6356752,31424518`) and I need to add in Excel. Could you please help me how to do it?

Excel adds it as `635675231424518` or `635,675,231,424,518`

Comment: Format the cell as `Text` before adding the value.

Comment: I must use a formula to make some calculations and I am not sure if I can do this with coordinates formatted as Text.

Comment: The value will need to come in as text or Excel will try to convert it to a number.  You will need to deal with the conversion in the formula.  Which is simple.

Comment: It's definitely worth looking at COMPLEX number types in Excel if you're working with coordinates - you can do several useful calculations on (x,y) pairs without writing your own code, including addition.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you need to make sure the cells are formatted as text before you insert them in to excel. And when you insert them, you must Paste Special with "Match Destination Formatting". If you need to perform calculations, you can split these up in to two cells with Text to Columns using comma as the delimiter. Then when you have performed the calculations, you can concatenate the values together and add a comma back in between them.